# How to close Shopee pop up in selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to close the popup for the site https://shopee.com.my/ in selenium
Please check the below image.

[image]

I tried below, but getting errors like

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".shopee-popup__close-btn"}
```

Code:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("shopee-popup__close-btn").click()
```

Comment: please copy and paste the text component of the DOM into the question.

Comment: @D.L I am not able to copy the code.. can you please check the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in shadow root.

**Code:**

```
driver_path = r'C:\\Users\\***\\***\\chromedriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)

driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

driver.get("https://shopee.com.my/")

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='English']"))).click()

try:
   time.sleep(3)
   close_btn = driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector("#main shopee-banner-popup-stateful").shadowRoot.querySelector("div.home-popup__close-area div.shopee-popup__close-btn")')
   close_btn.click()
   print('Clicked successfully')
except:
   print('Could not clicked')
   pass
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But, it' not working. Please check below output. "Could not clicked"

Comment: My bad, did not see it was in shadow-root, Updated above, Please verify.

Comment: Improved the locator as well.

Comment: @user15380124: yw!